# python array slicing range with [:,:]

Tags: python, numpy

I'm testing a array slicing there is a problem.

I want to print `(1,1)~(3,3)` values, however python prints `(1,1)~(2,2)` why?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.reshape(np.arange(25), (5,5))
print(a[1:3, 1:3])
```

Comment: That's the Python convention the left end is included the right end is excluded. Advantage: the difference of right and left gives the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 3 in your example is exclusive. Use 4 instead:

```
print(a[1:4, 1:4])
```

When using Python's start:stop:step slice notation, start is inclusive, but stop is not.